# unspecified javascript error in c# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've got a webbrowser control in a winforms application which automates a tedious form completion process involving hundrends of records each time.

My problem is that I get an unspecified javascript error (code:0) only when I run the application.
The script won't crash when I use IE11.
I've implemented the required registry changes (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION - I use 11000 for IE11).

The application used to work error free with IE9 (9000) and IE10 (left it with 9000 which worked).
I've read elsewhere that there may be a problem with asp.net recognizing IE11 but I can't find a fix for my system (Windows 7 64bit) and I don't want to just supress the script error because it also causes huge delays (it's probably the error since I had no such problems with the older IE versions).

I've read similar questions on the internet but no answer that fits my case was sufficient. For the time being I've set the ScriptErrorsSuppression to true but I'm not happy with that. Any ideas?